# Sorting a Cursor in Android to be used in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sorting, cursor

I'm doing a project for my Android class. The app is very ugly and not very useful, but it's to demonstrate that we can implement Content Providers. The problem I'm having is sorting the Cursor. Here is my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
String[] projection = new String[] {Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection , null, null, "Phone.CONTACT_ID ASC");
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, // Context.
            R.layout.rows,
            mCursor,                                              
            new String[] {Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, 
            new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Do you need the list to be sorted initially, or do you need to be able to sort the listview after it's displayed?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of doing this:

```
..., "Phone.CONTACT_ID ASC");
```

try this

```
..., Phone.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");
```